# Object creation during inheritance

Tags: java

```
public class Task {
}

class SubTask extends Task {
    public SubTask() {
        new Task();
    }
}

class SimpleTask extends SubTask {
    public SimpleTask() {
        new SubTask();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleTask s = new SimpleTask();
    }
}
```

How many objects will be created if I run this code?
If `new SubTask()` and `new Task()` inside constructors create new instance, how they can be referenced from main?

Comment: Two: one `SubTask`, and one `Task`.  As written, `SimpleTask` is not refereenced.

Comment: It might be useful to understand that the created SubTask will be inaccessible and eventually garbage collected

Comment: Given the inheritance structure, I don't think this code does what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

> How many objects will be created if i run this code

2
by `new SubTask()` in main and `new Task()` in constructor.

> If new SubTask() an new Task() insie constructors creates new instance,how they can be referenced from main

You are creating anonymous objects so they can't be accessed once created apart from the line in which they have been created.

Answer (score 0):

No objects will be created, because your code will not compile. 
SimbleTask != SimpleTask